# Get the style of input placeholder in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the style of input placeholder in my directive.
Following code doesn't seem to work. It only gives me the style of input and not the placeholder.

**Code**:

```
getComputedStyle(
      this.elm.nativeElement,
      '::placeholder'
    );
    text.font =
      fontStyle + ' ' + fontWeight + ' ' + fontSize + ' ' + fontFamily;
```

Slackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resizer-directive-ncbqme?file=app%2Fresizable.ts

So far I couldn't find any other way. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the computed style of the placeholder text in an input element within your Angular directive. However, directly accessing the ::placeholder pseudo-element with getComputedStyle won't work, as pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM tree and cannot be accessed this way.

Comment: Do you know any other way to do it?